# Using pydispatch and decorators for class methods

Tags: python, decorator, class-method

I am trying something fairly simple. I want to write a decorator which turns a class method in an event handler using pydispatcher. Here is my down-to-the-essentials approach:

```
from pydispatch.dispatcher import connect,send,Any

SIGNAL = "test"

def triggered(func):
    connect(func,signal=SIGNAL,sender = Any)
    return func

class P(object):
    @triggered
    def a(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print "yay"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = P()
    send(signal=SIGNAL,sender="")
```

This throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "util.py", line 35, in <module>
    send(signal=SIGNAL,sender="")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydispatch/dispatcher.py", line 338, in send
    **named
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
TypeError: a() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You registered a *function in a class*. This means that *just* the function is registered, not a bound method. Functions are not bound to an instance, so no `self` argument is being passed in.

You cannot hope to use the decorator on regular methods in a class definition, because the required context (an instance) is not available at that time.

You'd have to create an instance *first*, then register the method bound to that instance for this to work:

```
class P(object):
    def a(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "yay"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = P()
    triggered(p.a)
    send(signal=SIGNAL,sender="")
```

Now `triggered()` registers the `p.a` bound method; calling that method will then pass in `p` as the `self` argument when called.

You could alternatively make the `a` method a *static* or *class* method. A static method is essentially just a function; it never takes a `self` argument. This means you can register it as a signal handler, but you'll never get the benefits of using a class:

```
class P(object):
    @staticmethod
    @triggered
    def a(*args, **kwargs):
        print "yay"
```

If you make it a classmethod, you'll get the class passed in (still not an instance), and you'll *have* to do the registering outside the class to ensure you get a bound method:

```
class P(object):
    @classmethod
    def a(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "yay"

triggered(P.a)
```

Comment: So the core of the problem is that every event system must address instances, while decorators add static functionality. Do I see this in the right light?

Comment: @Kai: decorators act on the function as it is created; functions in the class body are created before the class is created. Thus your decorator registers just the function, not a method (which are created by referencing a function as an attribute on a class or instance). If you want to address a *bound method* you need to create an instance first. It really depends on what you want to have as context when the event fires.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Unfortunately this made my first idea impossible to implement, on the upside I learnt a lot about decorators. Thanks for sharing!